# Coroutine was never awaited. Can I make this synchronous?

Tags: python, telegram, python-telegram-bot

Using python-telegram-bot, I recently installed the --pre version which broke this code.
It seems now it wants everything to be async. In this example, I use code that has nothing to do with telegram bot to decide what will be the value of `mymsg`, so I don't need/want to havea commandHandler, I just want to be able to send a message in a Telegram channel whenever I decide so in my code

```
async def teleg_mail(msg):
    bot = telegram.Bot('TOKEN')
    keyboard = [[InlineKeyboardButton("Publish", callback_data='1///'+msg)]]
    reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)
    await bot.send_message('CHANNEL',msg, reply_markup=reply_markup)

def main() -> None:
    #...
    mymsg="code above will decide what's in this string"
    teleg_mail(mymsg)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I used async and await because I was getting error, but even when using it, now I get

```
 RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'teleg_mail' was never awaited
```

And I cannot use await on teleg_mail() because it's not in an async function...
How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

```
import asyncio

async def main() -> None:
    #...
    mymsg="code above will decide what's in this string"
    await teleg_mail(mymsg)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Comment: That actually works, eventhough I get this warning:

DeprecationWarning: There is no current event loop
  loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
I wonder if there is a cleaner way to do this condidering python-telegram-bot already uses asyncio afaik

Comment: Yes, the method is dirty, there should be better one :)

Comment: The main point is that you *need* an event loop. In this toy example, you might use `asyncio.run(main)`. In your actual code, how you create and/or access an event loop will differ.

Answer (score 0):

For switching from v13.x to v20.x, I highly recommend reading the [v20.0a0 release notes](https://t.me/pythontelegrambotchannel/114) as well as the [transition guide](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Transition-guide-to-Version-20.0). Please also note that the recommended way to use the bot methods without handlers is descriped [here](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Introduction-to-the-API).

---

Disclaimer: I'm currently the maintainer of `python-telegram-bot`.

Comment: How is it possible to do both. I want to send a message, but also use handlers:

```
def bot_listen():
    application = ApplicationBuilder().token(TELEGRAM_BOT_TOKEN).build()
    
    handle_message = MessageHandler(filters.ALL, message_handler)
    
    application.add_handler(handle_message)
    application.run_polling()
```

I will get `RuntimeError: Cannot close a running event loop` whenever i convert my main fn into async, however that is required to use the send_message method.